# Cannot stop UIActivityIndicatorView using regionDidChangeAnimated MapKit

Tags: ios, mapkit, uiactivityindicatorview

Basically I display a UIActivityIndicatorView that is a property and is synthesised and is in its own start animating method. I initialise this indicator and add it as a subview like the below

```
-(void)startLoader{
//regionChange is the ivar for UIActivitiyIndicatorView
self.regionChange = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
self.regionChange.frame = CGRectMake(145.0f, 180.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f);
[self.view addSubview:self.regionChange];
[self.regionChange startAnimating];
 }
```

and start the animation when the below method is called using map kit.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{

//This calls the activity start method
[self startLoader];

}
```

The indicator displays correctly and starts animating. When the map region changes it does a post request to a server and receives an XML in the response that is parsed using NSXMLParser. When the parsing has stopped it updates the map which is when I call the stop Method for the indicator however it never fires to stop it. This is whats in my stop method.

```
-(void)stopLoader{    

[self.regionChange stopAnimating];
[self.regionChange removeFromSuperView];
 NSlog (@"IS THIS EVER CALLED");

}
```

I have also tried the hidesWhenStopped however this and the above is never called?

Comment: Can you include the xml callbacks that call the stop method?

Comment: Also, have you added an NSLog in the close method to ensure the method is being called?

Comment: @bryanmac yes I have logged it and the stop method does get called however the stop animating never seems to fire?

Comment: removeFromSuperView should work - I do that in my sample but I don't call stopAnimating (no need).  Can you include the startLoader method?

Comment: @bryanmac interestingly if I move the stop method call outside the parser method and add a selector with a delayafter 5 seconds to the regionDidChangeAnimated it still does not stop the indicator so it cant be that the parser is locking the thread because i only call this method when parsing has finished.

Comment: @bryanmac I have edited my answer to include the start method. Thanks

Comment: added a guess as an answer.  I think self.loader != self.regionChange.  To be sure, you need to include your property definitions, synthesize or methods.

Comment: @bryanmac sorry yeah I just provided this as an example regionChange is the name of the ivar and is what I am calling please ignore the referecnce for loader. I have edited answer now.